# datagridview cellvaluedchanged event reuse it in other datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can i reuse a cellvaluechanged event in other datagridview with the same function. instead of making another cellvaluechanged event, can i reuse the same cellvaluechanged event. how can i do it?

i have 4 datagridviews hidden from tab pages with the same functions.

My application is a grading system, divided by 4 datagridviews, prelim,midterm,prefinal and final datagridviews.

```
private void dgvPrelim_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e, DataGridView dgv)
{
    if (dgvPrelimLec.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
        string studentID = dgvPrelimLec.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

        string data;
        var row0 = dgvPrelimLec.Rows[0];

        //if row index zero is selected
        if (row0.Selected)
        {
            if (dgvPrelimLec.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value == DBNull.Value)
            {
                data = "null";
            }
            else
            {
                data = dgvPrelimLec.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
            }

            //attendance
            if (dgvPrelimLec.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Index >= 3 && dgvPrelimLec.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Index <= 16)
            {
                int attendanceColumnIndex = dgvPrelimLec.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Index - 2;
                string AttendanceTableName = "A" + attendanceColumnIndex;

                string sql = string.Format("UPDATE LectureOver SET " + AttendanceTableName + " = ISNULL(" + data + ",null) WHERE studentID= '" + studentID + "' AND subjectID = '" + getSubjectID + "'");
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                //and so on..... codes
```

Comment: Yes. You can associate the same method to as many events as you wish, even to different event types (by assuming that all of them have the same signature).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can bind as many datagridview as you want to a single event. You can bind those like below in your C# code -

```
dgvPrelimLec.CellValueChanged += dgvPrelim_CellValueChanged;
dgvMidterm.CellValueChanged += dgvPrelim_CellValueChanged;
dgvPrefinal .CellValueChanged += dgvPrelim_CellValueChanged;
dgvFinal.CellValueChanged += dgvPrelim_CellValueChanged;



private void dgvPrelim_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dvg = (DataGridView)sender;

        .....
    }
```

Comment: since my every datagridview functions use different table in database, then i need to use parameters. so how can i activate specific datagridview for that event?

Comment: If you need specific functionality for each datagridview event, it is better to use different event for each of them.

Comment: ok sir, thank you for the information, i think i need to create event for every datagridview since they are stored in different tables.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `dgvPrelimLec` with `currentView`:

```
var currentView = (DataGridView)sender;
if (currentView.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
{
    string studentID = currentView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    //and so on...
}
```

And subscribe this handler to all your views.

Comment: You should follow your own advice and replace `dgvPrelimLec` with `currentView` :)

Comment: @varocarbas ahaha :) copy-paste. thank you very much!

Comment: where should i put my datagridview name property?